Alternative definition of ergodicity for physical systems
Imagine we have a physical system whose dynamics are given by its hamiltonian H, defined in a space A. My question is whether the following definition is equivalent to saying that the system is ergodic:
The physical system is ergodic if, for every set of initial conditions $\vec{X}_{0}\in A$, the trajectory that follows the system, $T(\vec{X}_{0})\subset A$, is dense in A.

No, what you defined is a minimal dynamical system. Ergodicity is different.
